# ELK - Logstash - GROK Pattern : From following log given I want to extract all the log starting from {@timestamp

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack, grok

Jul 13 03:19:38 tciapp bw/[o:01E45HV1D7GGJQZ49AKS4NW7QV:o][a:bkwjui6nb6i3xdp6zjvncbk77ukuoghk:a][c:a188c69b8193:c]: { "timestamp": 1594610381, "time": "03:19:41.017", "level": "INFO", "appname": "HZ3PLAUpdateService", "apptype": "bw", "orgid": "01E45HV1D7GGJQZ49AKS4NW7QV", "appid": "bkwjui6nb6i3xdp6zjvncbk77ukuoghk", "instance": "a188c69b8193", "message": "[bwEngThread:In-Memory Process Worker-7] c.t.b.p.g.L.T.shared.LogInfo - {'@timestamp':'2020-07-13T03:19:41.012Z','client.domain':'E','techem.propertynumber':'0015011257','country':'DE','module':'HZ3_PLAUpdateService','log.level':'info','message':'Finished HZ3PLAUpdateService SOAP Request for 0015011257','error.message':'','techem.pr.number':'0015/011257','keys':[{'key':'pr.number.key','value':'0015011257'}]} " }

Comment: I want output as {'@timestamp':'2020-07-13T03:19:41.012Z','client.domain':'E','techem.propertynumber':'0015011257','country':'DE','module':'HZ3_PLAUpdateService','log.level':'info','message':'Finished HZ3PLAUpdateService SOAP Request for 0015011257','error.message':'','techem.pr.number':'0015/011257','keys':[{'key':'pr.number.key','value':'0015011257'}]} " }

Comment: I am not able to create Grok pattern for same. Please Help

Comment: On Using (?<log>{'@.*)  Grok pattern I got json as {
  "log": [
    [
      "{'@timestamp':'2020-07-13T03:19:41.012Z','client.domain':'E','techem.propertynumber':'0015011257','country':'DE','module':'HZ3_PLAUpdateService','log.level':'info','message':'Finished HZ3PLAUpdateService SOAP Request for 0015011257','error.message':'','techem.pr.number':'0015/011257','keys':[{'key':'pr.number.key','value':'0015011257'}]} ""
    ]
  ]
}

Comment: But I want my json to start from {@timestamp

Answer (score 0):

Please find the filter part for your logstash configuration:

```
filter {
    grok {
      match => { "message" => "%{GREEDYDATA:logs} \- \{%{GREEDYDATA:KV}\} \"" }
      overwrite => [ "message" ]
          }

      kv {
           source => "KV"
           value_split => ":"
           field_split => ","
           target => "msg"
         }
  }
```

I have used [Grok Debugger](https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/) to filter your log message into two parts. You can the output here.
[image]

Then, I have used [KV Filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-kv.html#plugins-filters-kv-value_split) to split the fields with their values.

You can try it out and check whether it’s working you or not.